# Autoresize header to stay on one row

Tags: image, css, css-float, autoresize

I'm currently customizing wordpress layout for one company and I have a problem with layout.

I have a logo in header and to the right of it is navigation. But when I'm zooming in, at one point the navigation skips to the next row.

I'd like to ask you how should I keep them on one row when zooming.

Page can be found on dev.machala.cz

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: please add your code or demo what you have tried for this?

Comment: It can be seen just how it is on dev.machala.cz and fiddled with through for example mozzila console...
There is a lot of code involved.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom your page that means viewport size is getting lower and your page starts using your Media Query for that width.

If you don't want to break your menu to down. You have to remove your Media Query.

This is not an issue. You can leave it as it is.

Comment: It's OK that it changes to dropdown for mobile devices. 

Problem is, that on 1200px display width it looks ok, on 1199px top menu skips under logo, which is not desireable.

Using screenfly for testing.

Comment: You have to make logo small and you  can also reduce the left and right padding of your menu-item.

For doing that you should use a media query

@media(max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
// write your code here 
}

You are using bootstrap which breakpoint is 1199px and it goes to till 992px.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this for layout purposes on mobile and tablet maybe consider this -

Try changing the font size of the menu text to:

font-size: 1vw;

and then change the media query for the of the mobile menu toggle bar to 1000px

and set the font size back to normal in that media query.

Using VW make the font scale with the width of the browser.

Doing this means you'll be able to shrink the browser for slightly longer and then the media query for the toggle will appear sooner avoiding the text moving to a new row.